# How to replace data from one column into a placeholder in another

Tags: google-sheets

Some thing that does this:

I'm thinking in Google Sheets have column A be let's say City, and column B be let's say address, then I want to paste something into column C like:

"Are you looking for Dentistry in [CIty Name(pull content from column A)] then come to our dental clinic in [Address (Pull content from column B)]"

and then have column D be the outputs that I can copy/paste, I also need it to be able to work with multiple rows but I paste the same thing into row C all the way down.

Comment: Google sheets is off topic for this site.  If you want an Excel answer that is on topic, but may not be transferable to sheets, they are not the same.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask] as well a link to a demo spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create 3 Column Names such as **City,Address,Output** from A4 to C4

Step 2: Fill City and Address as you want

Step 3: Choose D4 as your desired OUTPUT Sample Text with Variable ***Data_City*** and ***Data_Address***

Step 4: Use Substitute for replace variables

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($D$3,"Data_City",A5),"Data_Address",B5)
```

[image]